# Can flavoring extracts be added to inverted sugar?

Tags: candy, chemistry

I'd like to try doing a recipe with inverted sugar ([hand pulled cotton candy](https://www.eater.com/video/2017/9/5/16254036/recipe-hand-pulled-cotton-candy)), but am entirely new to candy making. I have the instructions to create inverted sugar, but would like to add a flavoring (as opposed to just the dye used in the video). I've tried googling it, but can't find too much information.

I've read the Honey is very similar to inverted sugar, but has some impurities that give it it's color and distinctive flavor, so I know chemically inverted sugar is entirely possible, but I don't have the time or resources to figure out how to make bees produce blue raspberry honey.

I've considered using jello, but I imagine with the gelatin the end result wouldn't be anywhere near the texture I'm looking for. Is there any way I can manage to impart more than just "raw pure sugar" into this recipe?

Comment: With dragon's beard candy, you are working with sugar candy in a malleable state... you need to dredge it in something powdery and dry often to keep the threads from sticking.  Powdered sugar, I think, or possibly some kind of starch, it's been a while since I looked at a recipe.  Point being, you should probably be able to add any kind of powdered flavoring to the dredging powder, as long as it's finely ground enough... though it may take some work to get the ratios and flavoring strength right.

Answer (score 3):

It should work, but the notion is that the flavoring should be intense so that just a little would need to be used. You don't want to substantially dilute the syrup. So a teaspoon to the two cups of water used to make the syrup would be fine.

The other thing is that the flavoring must either be a liquid or completely dissolve in the sugar solution. What you don't want is any solid particulate matter in the cooked syrup since particles will be nucleation points upon which crystals would form.

*It is just some sugar you'd be wasting if it doesn't work. Experiment...*